# .on("drag", function()) and .on("contextmenu", function()) does not work when used on the same code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a function which appends an svg in a gant chart. .on("drag") is to allow the svg to to move within the gant chart. The .on("contextmenu", remove) calls a function which deletes the svg. But it does not work. Its showing an error Unexpected token . in line of .on("contextmenu"). Can I not use .on("drag") and .on("contextmenu") in the same code? what is wrong here?

```
var bodySelection = d3.select(".chart");

 var circleSelection = bodySelection.append("rect")

                                  .attr("x", this.x_start)
                                  .attr("y", this.y_stage)
                                  .attr("width", this.pt)                
                                  .attr("height", 25)
                                  .attr("id",this.gantchart_id)

                                  .style("fill", this.color)
                                  .call(drag);
                                  .on("contextmenu", remove)
gantchart[gc_order].id = this.gantchart_id;
gantchart[gc_order].start_point = (this.x_start-80)/5;
gantchart[gc_order].processing_time = this.pt/5;
index = index+1;
gantchart.push({id: "g00", start_point: 0, next_stage: 0, index});                                  
gc_order = gc_order+1;
```

Comment: Just a typo, you  have a semicolon on the line before

Comment: To further specify what @aw04 said, your line `.call(drag);` should be `.call(drag)`.

Comment: Tanq very much.!! Its working fine now!!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
.style("fill", this.color)
.call(drag);
.on("contextmenu", remove)
```

To:

```
.style("fill", this.color)
.call(drag)
.on("contextmenu", remove)
```

Remove your semicolon. For future reference,

> Unexpected token

is always a syntax error. Once you fix the syntax, the error goes away.

Comment: @eyathu Your welcome. I take it everything works? If so, can you close out the question? ;) Thanks.